# SOAP service call through javascript 405 method not allowed Error.

Tags: javascript, web-services, soap

I have implemented a **SOAP** service call in javascript, it is working fine and I am getting response when executing it through phone-gap in android or iOS but when I try to execute it in browser, I am getting an error of 405.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
>
> Failed to load resource: Invalid HTTP status code 405
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'serviceurl'. Invalid HTTP status code 405

And the code that implemented **SOAP** service call is as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var IDcardNo = 'IHL1167618';
        //function for executing the soap service c
        function soap() {
            //creating headers
            xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://123.176.47.52/SOAPservice/Service.asmx', true);
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""); 
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("POST","/SOAPservice/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1");
            xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://tempuri.org/GetPSDetails");
            
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= handler;  
            alert("set request header completed");  
            
            //SOAP Request XML format
            var sr =
                '<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
                '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
                    '<soap:Body>'+
                        '<GetPSDetails xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">'+
                            '<IDCARDNO>' + IDcardNo + '</IDCARDNO>'+
                        '</GetPSDetails>'+
                    '</soap:Body>'+
                '</soap:Envelope>';
            xmlhttp.send(sr);
        }
        function handler() {  
            if(xmlhttp.readyState ==4  && xmlhttp.status==200) {  
                //status of the request
             alert("readystate:"+xmlhttp.readyState+"status:"+xmlhttp.status);
                //response formt the server
             alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
         }  
    }  
    </script>
```

Please help me, to find where did I do the mistake?